# Navigation crashes app

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, crash

I have an app with multiple view controllers with a navigation controller handling the transitions between them.  when i get to the final page i have a bar button item called "home" to return me to the first page.  this works but when i try to go back through the app it crashes.

it returns this as my error message:

```
  @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

and says :

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable zombies so we can see what line it's crashing on?

Also you should be calling popToRootViewController or popToViewController: to get back to a specific view controller.  Trying to do anything fancy on your own can be really bad.